# How to Read JSON block in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am getting response from webRequest below is the code,

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();

        while (reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            objText = reader.ReadLine();

            MyObject myobj= (MyObject)js.Deserialize<MyObject>(objText);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting JSON response in below format, I want to bind this JSON response with myobj.

```
{"Results":[{"Id":"571611","ModerationStatus":"APPROVED","LastModificationTime":
        "2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00"
        ,"IsRatingsOnly":true,"TotalCommentCount":0,"Rating":5,"RatingRange":5,"IsRecommended":true,"TotalFeedbackCount":0,"TotalPositiveFeedbackCount":0,"TotalNegativeFeedbackCount":0,"DisplayLocale":"en_US","SubmissionTime":
        "2011-05-25T00:00:00-05:00"
        ,"IsFeatured":false,"LastModeratedTime":
        "2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00"
        ,"ProductId":"3240234","AuthorId":"z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra"},{"Id":"571612","ModerationStatus":"APPROVED","LastModificationTime":
        "2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00"
        ,"IsRatingsOnly":true,"TotalCommentCount":0,"Rating":5,"RatingRange":5,"IsRecommended":true,"TotalFeedbackCount":0,"TotalPositiveFeedbackCount":0,"TotalNegativeFeedbackCount":0,"DisplayLocale":"en_US","SubmissionTime":
        "2011-05-25T00:00:00-05:00"
        ,"IsFeatured":false,"LastModeratedTime":
        "2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00"
        ,"ProductId":"3240234","AuthorId":"zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp"}],"Includes":{"Products":{"3240234":{"Id":"3240234","Name":"Rosner Chevrolet","Description":"Brevard County","BrandExternalId":"01","Brand":{"Id":"01","Name":"Personal Accounts"},"CategoryId":"324","ProductPageUrl":"https://www.sccu.com/personal/vehicle-loans/dealer-review.asp?did=234&dealerName=Rosner+Chevrolet"}},"Authors":{"z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra":{"Id":"z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra","ModerationStatus":"NONE"},"zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp":{"Id":"zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp","ModerationStatus":"NONE"}}},"HasErrors":false,"Offset":0,"Limit":2,"TotalResults":25}
```

I want to read this JSON blocks(This JSON blocks having more than one value) one by one and stores in to the objectlist.

Comment: you are using "ReadToEnd();" so your stream-cursor is now at the end of the stream. after that you check if "reader.EndOfStream" is true. it allways will be true cause of "ReadToEnd();". Also inside your while-loop you use "reader.ReadLine();" to read the next line of the stream. what allways will return a null-object cause you dont have any next lines to read....

Comment: your Json String is in Wrong Format !! thats why deserialize if not working    .. paste your Json String here http://json.parser.online.fr/  ... i tried your Json String .. its showing errors

Comment: @Aravind, Jsonlint result : Valid JSON.

Comment: I have updated my answer please see it...

Comment: @ Irshad .. it works fine in my code... :) if it works for you instead of saying thanks accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this first try to parse your Json String here \

http://json.parser.online.fr/

if it passed there then goto   http://json2csharp.com/   ... paste your string ... it will generate a Class with Attributes

then

paste the class inside your code . and create new object for the class

and call Deserialize

```
   JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var Data = DeserializeFromJson<RootObject>("Json String");
 public T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ObjJSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        T deserializedProduct = ObjJSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        return deserializedProduct;
    }


public class Result
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string ModerationStatus { get; set; }
public string LastModificationTime { get; set; }
public bool IsRatingsOnly { get; set; }
public int TotalCommentCount { get; set; }
public int Rating { get; set; }
public int RatingRange { get; set; }
public bool IsRecommended { get; set; }
public int TotalFeedbackCount { get; set; }
public int TotalPositiveFeedbackCount { get; set; }
public int TotalNegativeFeedbackCount { get; set; }
public string DisplayLocale { get; set; }
public string SubmissionTime { get; set; }
public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
public string LastModeratedTime { get; set; }
public string ProductId { get; set; }
public string AuthorId { get; set; }
 }

  public class Brand
  {
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class __invalid_type__3240234
 {
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string BrandExternalId { get; set; }
public Brand Brand { get; set; }
public string CategoryId { get; set; }
public string ProductPageUrl { get; set; }
   }

public class Products
{
public __invalid_type__3240234 __invalid_name__3240234 { get; set; }
 }

 public class Z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string ModerationStatus { get; set; }
}

 public class Zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp
{ 
public string Id { get; set; }
public string ModerationStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Authors
{
public Z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra { get; set; }
public Zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp { get; set; }
 }

 public class Includes
{
public Products Products { get; set; }
public Authors Authors { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
public Includes Includes { get; set; }
public bool HasErrors { get; set; }
public int Offset { get; set; }
public int Limit { get; set; }
public int TotalResults { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream()))
   {
     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();  
     MyObject myobj= (MyObject)js.Deserialize<MyObject>(objText);
   }
 }
```

The while-loop should not be needed, as you have already read to the end of the stream.
And as long as MyObject can be parsed too from the json, the deserialization should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this into a C# object with a single line of code using [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString);
}

private static string JsonString
{
    get
    {
        return @"{""Results"":[{""Id"":""571611"",""ModerationStatus"":""APPROVED"",""LastModificationTime"":
                ""2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00""
                ,""IsRatingsOnly"":true,""TotalCommentCount"":0,""Rating"":5,""RatingRange"":5,""IsRecommended"":true,""TotalFeedbackCount"":0,""TotalPositiveFeedbackCount"":0,""TotalNegativeFeedbackCount"":0,""DisplayLocale"":""en_US"",""SubmissionTime"":
                ""2011-05-25T00:00:00-05:00""
                ,""IsFeatured"":false,""LastModeratedTime"":
                ""2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00""
                ,""ProductId"":""3240234"",""AuthorId"":""z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra""},{""Id"":""571612"",""ModerationStatus"":""APPROVED"",""LastModificationTime"":
                ""2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00""
                ,""IsRatingsOnly"":true,""TotalCommentCount"":0,""Rating"":5,""RatingRange"":5,""IsRecommended"":true,""TotalFeedbackCount"":0,""TotalPositiveFeedbackCount"":0,""TotalNegativeFeedbackCount"":0,""DisplayLocale"":""en_US"",""SubmissionTime"":
                ""2011-05-25T00:00:00-05:00""
                ,""IsFeatured"":false,""LastModeratedTime"":
                ""2011-10-31T05:36:33-05:00""
                ,""ProductId"":""3240234"",""AuthorId"":""zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp""}],""Includes"":{""Products"":{""3240234"":{""Id"":""3240234"",""Name"":""Rosner Chevrolet"",""Description"":""Brevard County"",""BrandExternalId"":""01"",""Brand"":{""Id"":""01"",""Name"":""Personal Accounts""},""CategoryId"":""324"",""ProductPageUrl"":""https://www.sccu.com/personal/vehicle-loans/dealer-review.asp?did=234&dealerName=Rosner+Chevrolet""}},""Authors"":{""z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra"":{""Id"":""z7knrbjunvi022pe4swqp18fra"",""ModerationStatus"":""NONE""},""zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp"":{""Id"":""zsknvekklaxl56nzwliultz5mp"",""ModerationStatus"":""NONE""}}},""HasErrors"":false,""Offset"":0,""Limit"":2,""TotalResults"":25}";
    }
}
```

The object will be an array of the outer JSON objects, if **MyObject** matches the JSON structure, then the following should work:

```
var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(JsonString);
```

Comment: did you tried .. i have tried JavaScript Serializer and Newtonsoft .. both returns null .. i have posted my code please check it

Comment: @Aravind I didn't go to the trouble of creating the MyObject model because I don't have the time, but the first piece of code (using the non generic method and returning an object) works as expected, I was able to verify this by placing a breakpoint and checking in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ Jmk  var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString);  this one will work because you are directly passing the string ... but we need a solution like what you mentioned na by passing object ... so only asked thanks for replying